# Ambiguous type variable in combination of sqrt and floor

Tags: haskell, types

Trying to implement a function for listing all prime numbers in some range of numbers, I know when I am checking for factors I do not have to check beyond the sqrt of that that number.

```
factors n = [x | x <- [1..(floor (sqrt n))], mod n x == 0]
prime n = factors n == [1,n]
listPrimesFromTill n z = [ xs | xs <- [n..z], prime xs == True]
```

I've been browsing for answers and I tried various methods like type checking using

```
factors :: (RealFrac b, Integral c, Floating b) => b -> c
```

but have had no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it make sense to use `Floating` as an input constraint on `factors`? That would mean that it's valid to call `factor 3.14`. What should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you looked at the code you wrote and figured the types out after. In general, Haskell development is the other way around: First you figure out the types, then you implement the functions. What type should `factors` have? Well, you can only factorize integers, so something of type, so this seems sensible:

```
factor :: Integral a => a -> [a]
```

Now when trying to compile your code we get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `sqrt` from the context (Integral a)
```

and

```
Could not deduce (RealFrac a) arising from a use of `sqrt` from the context (Integral a)
```

It complains that you specified `Integral a` but it needs `Floating a` for `sqrt`. We can do this by usinf `fromIntegral`:

```
sqrt         ::          Floating a => a -> a
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b

factors :: Integral a => a -> [a]       vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
factors n = [x | x <- [1..(floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n)))], mod n x == 0]
```

To preserve readability,

```
factors n = [x | x <- [1..isqrt n], mod n x == 0]
    where isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it doesnt evalualte to anything!

Comment: @FredPark please be more specific. What doen't work?

Comment: modifying the code with your recommendation (which makes sense) does not find primes from my desired range.

Comment: @FredPark What is the error? Does it produce an infinite loop? Which output do you get?